# NSAttributedStringKey error with swift 4

Tags: ios, swift, swift4, nsattributedstring, nsattributedstringkey

After updating to Swift 4 I am getting an error on this code

```
    attributes["NSFont"] = font
    attributes["NSColor"] = UIColor(red: 0.0, green: 0.0, blue: 0.0, alpha: 1)
```

> Cannot subscript a value of type '[NSAttributedStringKey : Any]' with
>   an index of type 'String'

I was able to fix the first line by replacing `["NSFont"]` with `NSAttributedStringKey.font` but I am not sure how to fix the second one.

Comment: NSAttributedStringKey.backgroundColor ,NSAttributedStringKey.foregroundColor

Comment: `attributes["NSFont"]` That's a not recommended way to do so. Use `NSFontAttributeName` and `NSForegroundColorAttributeName` for the other one. What if tomorrow iOS SDK decided that instead of `NSFont`  for the value it would be `UIFont` (which seems more "iOS")? That's why at first place that code is not recommended. Then with Swift 4, use the `NSAttributedStringKey` correspondant.

Answer (score 19):

In swift 4 - NSAttributedString representation is completely changed.

Replace your attribute dictionary - `attributes` type, from `[String : Any]` to `[NSAttributedStringKey : Any]`  or `[NSAttributedString.Key : Any]`, if you've not done.

Try this in

#### Swift 4.2+:

```
attributes[NSAttributedString.Key.font] = font
attributes[NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor] = UIColor(red: 0.0, green: 0.0, blue: 0.0, alpha: 1)
```

#### Swift 4.0 & 4.1:

```
attributes[NSAttributedStringKey.font] = font
attributes[NSAttributedStringKey.foregroundColor] = UIColor(red: 0.0, green: 0.0, blue: 0.0, alpha: 1)
```

Here is note from Apple document: [NSAttributedString.Key](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsattributedstringkey)

Answer (score 3):

Use `NSAttributedStringKey.foregroundColor` for the second one, keys are not Strings anymore, but enum constants.

```
attributes[NSAttributedStringKey.font] = font
attributes[NSAttributedStringKey.foregroundColor] = UIColor(red: 0.0, green: 0.0, blue: 0.0, alpha: 1)
```

You can find all the keys in the [official docs for NSAttributedStringKey](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsattributedstringkey).

Answer (score 1):

For Swift 3.3, `NSForegroundColorAttributeName`, `NSFontAttributeName` like

```
NSAttributedString(string: "text", attributes: [NSForegroundColorAttributeName : UIColor.white])
```

For Swift 4.0+

```
NSAttributedString(string: "text", attributes: [NSAttributedStringKey.foregroundColor : UIColor.white])
```